# Powershell Quotes Use asisstance

Tags: powershell, variables, arguments

Need some expert help from you guru's out there (after 3 days of trying on my own lol). Here the portion of my script that's failing:

```
$yy=(get-date).Year

Invoke-Command -ComputerName *ipaddress* -Credential $moveitcred {
move-item -path "C:\iCApps\Dev\LetterGenerator\Letters\FTS\EDMS\*.txt" -destination "C:\Moveitft\Dev\Letters\Outbound" -force
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -ArgumentList "a -y C:\Moveitft\Dev\Letters\archive\Letters$yy_.zip C:\Moveitft\Dev\Letters\Outbound\*.*"
}
```

The move works fine. AND the zip works fine, except when I want to include the the year varible ($yy) in the argument list. Powershell doesn't want to populate the variable to adjust the file name. Either it bombs out citing a $null, or the job completes with just a blank where the $yy should be.

If i run just $yy from the prompt, it does return the correct year value, so I'm guessing it an improper use of quotes. But after 3 days of googling and trying various combinations on my own, I'm throwing in the towel. Any help/guidance would be so GREATLY appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Change `Letters$yy_.zip` to either
`Letters$($yy)_.zip`
or
`Letters${yy}_.zip`.

Both of them work.

See: [PowerShell subexpression](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) and [PowerShell variable names](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/10/chapter-3-variables.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not about quoting is about variable scope. Inside the scriptblock you are executing, powershell knows nothing about the `$yy` var. So you need to tell it where to obtain the value.  You could do that using the `argumentList` parameter. I see that you already are doing that but you are doing it wrong (move-item doesn't support that parameter). Look the following examples to grasp the concept, I think with that you will solve your problem:

```
# this is fine and simple
$yy="Hello scriptblocks!"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { "whatever you want to run that use the an external var. $yy" } -ArgumentList $yy

# this is incorrect
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { "whatever you want to run that use the an external var. $yyCarefulWithThisText" } -ArgumentList $yy

# this shows how you could resolve the variable when you want to put text around
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { "whatever you want to run that use the an external var. $($yy)CarefulWithThisText" } -ArgumentList $yy

# output1: whatever you want to run that use the an external var. Hello scriptblocks!
# output2: whatever you want to run that use the an external var.
# output3: whatever you want to run that use the an external var. Hello scriptblocks!CarefulWithThisText
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried the above, thank you! I think this might boil down to powershell version. I'm trying to execute this on a server running powershell v2.0, against another 2012 Server.

I've shortened down the code to just the line in question (so I can "F8" it to test the results) Here it is:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName *ipaddress* -Credential $moveitcred {
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -argumentlist "a -y C:\Moveitft\Dev\Letters\archive\Letters${yy}.zip C:\Moveitft\Dev\Letters\Outbound*.*"
}

Both of your suggestions "work", in that the command processes, however its still not reading the variable correctly. Here's what I get as a resultant .zip

[image]

The reason I'm thinking its powershell, is becuase if I copy/paste the same command into powershell v4.0 on my own production machine, you can instantly see by the color coding that the "$yy" is being considered a variable because it turns red - and then the code works ok on from my PS4.0 machine.

On the PSv2.0 server i'm trying to get this to run from, that same line for "-argumentlist" appears all maroon/brown - including the $yy portion. So its kind of a hint whether it will work or not for me.

Comment: Is there a reason to assume that the target server has a different year than the one doing the invoke? Try to declare $yy inside the scriptblock, before the Start-Process line and see if that gets ya what ya need. Otherwise you might have to use -ArgumentList together with Invoke-Command

Comment: CORRECT! Thank you to mjsr senior as well, who actually go tme thinking about that yesterday. And then to you as well who confirmed it this morning :) This resolved it - declaring in the script block!